# PHP ODBC Extension - Data Source Name Too Long

Tags: php, linux, odbc, datasource, redhat

I've been trying to install the ODBC extension for PHP onto one of our servers (Redhat), and i think it got it installed correctly but now when i try to test the connection i get the error message about the data source name being too long... It sounds like a simple thing to fix, but i can't work out..how..or where.

Basically these are the settings i've got at the moment:

```
# odbcinst -j
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /root/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN SIze.......: 4
SQLSETPOSIROW......: 2
```

I've got my MySQL driver defined in the odbcinst.ini as such:

```
[MySQL]
Description    = ODBC for MySQL
Driver         = /usr/lib/libmyodbc5.so
Setup          = /usr/lib/libodbcmyS.so
FileUsage      = 1
```

I've double checked and the Driver & Setup paths are correct and pointing to the correct files.

So now I'm trying to add a System Data Source by editing the odbc.ini file. I've tried it in various different formats, following examples from different sites, e.g.

http://developer.mindtouch.com/en/kb/Using_the_ODBC_extension_on_Linux#Install_unixODBC

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-odbc-configuration-dsn-unix.html

As you can see i've commented some of them out and tried different ones:

```
;[mytest]
;driver = MySQL
;Database = moodle
;Server = localhost
;Socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

;[mynew]
;Description = MySQL
;Driver      = MySQL
;SERVER      = localhost
;USER        = root
;PASSWORD    = 
;PORT        = 3306
;DATABASE    = moodle

[Default]
Driver       = /usr/lib/libmyodbc5.so
Description  = Connector/ODBC 5 Driver DSN
SERVER       = localhost
PORT         =
USER         = root
Password     =
Database     = moodle
SOCKET       =
```

However, whenever i run

```
isql -v
```

to see if there are any problems, i always get:

```
[IM010][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name too long
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

My googling around the error only ever seems to turn up results for people having a connection string within something like ASP, nothing about how to get it working on the server in this way...

Could anyone offer me any advice/help?

If you need more information, let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  Hope we get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

When launching `isql` you have to specify the data source name as defined in the man page.

> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>    isql DSN [UID [PWD]] [options]
> ```
>
> OPTIONS
>
> ```
>    DSN    Name of the data source you want to connect to.
> ```

Given your configuration in `/etc/odbc.ini`, you would launch `isql -v Default` to test your connection. In the configuration file, the data source name is the one you've defined between brackets.